# Select top K value from a tensor with no duplication

Tags: pytorch, selection

`torch.Tensor.topk` provides an efficient way to extract top k values in a tensor along one dimension. Is it possible to restrict the top k value to be **non-repetitive**?

For example,

```
input = torch.tensor([0.2,0.2,0.1])
k = 2
dim = 0


output[0] = torch.tensor([0.2,0.1])
output[1] = torch.longtensor([0,2])
```

Comment: How do you wish this to behave if there are fewer unique values than k?

Comment: such case doesn't exist in my data collection.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply [`torch.unique`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unique.html) on the input tensor.

```
>>> input.unique().topk(k=2).values
tensor([0.2000, 0.1000])
```

Do note you will lose the indices at this point.

---

*Edit*: actually [`torch.unique`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unique.html) has an option to sort the results (the option is on by default).

```
>>> input
tensor([0.0000, 0.3000, 0.2000, 0.2000, 0.1000])

>>> input.unique(return_inverse=True)[1].unique(sorted=False)
tensor([1, 2, 3, 0])
```

Comment: is there a way to keep indices? they are very important to me.